# using eval to import namespaces in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to dump the contents of one namespace into another in javascript.  The only way I could figure to do this directly is as follows:

```
var CHESSMEN = {

  Chariot: function(color) {
    return {
      color: color,
      abbreviation: 'R',
      type: 'Chariot'
    };
  },

  Horse: function(color) {
    return {
      color: color,
      abbreviation: 'H',
      type: 'Horse'
    };
  },

  Elephant: function(color) {
    return {
      color: color,
      abbreviation: 'E',
      type: 'Elephant'
    };
  },

  Advisor: function(color) {
    return {
      color: color,
      abbreviation: 'A',
      type: 'Advisor'
    };
  },

  General: function(color) {
    return {
      color: color,
      abbreviation: 'G',
      type: 'General'
    };
  },

  Cannon: function(color) {
    return {
      color: color,
      abbreviation: 'C',
      type: 'Cannon'
    };
  },

  Soldier: function(color) {
    return {
      color: color,
      abbreviation: 'S',
      type: 'Soldier'
    };
  }
}
Object.freeze(CHESSMEN)

function Game(board) {

  for (var piece in CHESSMEN) {
    eval('var ' + piece + ' = CHESSMEN.' + piece);
  }

  if (typeof(board) === 'undefined') {
    var board = {
      a1: new Chariot('red'),
      b1: new Horse('red'),
      c1: new Elephant('red'),
      d1: new Advisor('red'),
      e1: new General('red'),
      f1: new Advisor('red'),
      g1: new Elephant('red'),
      h1: new Horse('red'),
      i1: new Chariot('red'),
      b3: new Cannon('red'),
      h3: new Cannon('red'),
      a4: new Soldier('red'),
      c4: new Soldier('red'),
      e4: new Soldier('red'),
      g4: new Soldier('red'),
      i4: new Soldier('red'),
      a10: new Chariot('black'),
      b10: new Horse('black'),
      c10: new Elephant('black'),
      d10: new Advisor('black'),
      e10: new General('black'),
      f10: new Advisor('black'),
      g10: new Elephant('black'),
      h10: new Horse('black'),
      i10: new Chariot('black'),
      b8: new Cannon('black'),
      h8: new Cannon('black'),
      a7: new Soldier('black'),
      c7: new Soldier('black'),
      e7: new Soldier('black'),
      g7: new Soldier('black'),
      i7: new Soldier('black')
    };
  }

  // et cetera
}
```

Here I am using a `for in` loop to iterate over the keys of a frozen object and using `eval` to dump those keys and their associated values into the scope of the `Game` constructor.  I have been told by many people not to use `eval`, but I do not see another way to directly merge namespaces.  Is this unsafe?  Would it be somehow better for me to be calling the chessmen constructors as properties of the `CHESSMEN` object?

Comment: Why do you need to *import* them? Why not just use as `CHESSMEN.Chariot` etc?

Comment: I want to know if there is any _disadvantage_ to importing them. But to address your question, I have no good reason to use `Chariot` over `CHESSMEN.Chariot`. I am simply curious as to whether this formulation is unsafe.

Comment: yes there is - you're doing something that's not required for solving the task. Your every step should be caused by some requirement. The opposite - when you do some weird things and justify them as "why not" - not true.

Comment: Btw, this question has nothing to do with "security". Or the "security" term usage should be clarified.

Comment: You are probably right about the tag @zerkms.  And about my namespaces.  Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but *heavily* discouraged and not possible in strict mode.

```
with (CHESSMEN) {
    // Now CHESSMEN's properties are available without saying "CHESSMEN.whatever"
    console.log(Chariot === CHESSMEN.Chariot); // logs "true"
}
```

I reiterate: this is a *bad idea*. It's harder to tell what any identifier refers to, it can run slower, and it's not forward compatible. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) for more details.

As for the safety of your eval: If at some later point, your code changes in such a way that `CHESSMEN` can have user-defined properties, an attacker could name a property `foo; doHorriblyEvilThing();` to cause your code to do something horribly evil.

Comment: Thank you.  I suppose I will just have to get used to keeping separate namespaces separate in my javascript.  I especially appreciate your point that even if there is not a current security problem, I will have to always worry about security when modifying the code in the future.

Comment: @HandyAndyShortStack: security of what? Are you protecting against yourself?

Answer (score 2):

As @zerkms pointed out, you should access them using `CHESSMEN.Chariot` etc:

```
var board = {
  a1: new CHESSMAN.Chariot('red'),
  b1: new CHESSMAN.Horse('red'),
  c1: new CHESSMAN.Elephant('red'),
  //etc.
```

Also, you almost definitely don't want your `Chariot` implemented the way you have it if you are going to be using `new`.  The pattern you want is:

```
  Chariot: function(color) {
    this.color = color;
    this.abbreviation = 'R';
    this.type = 'Chariot'
  },
```

Otherwise, when you call `new` what will be returned will be the object literal you are creating as opposed to an instance of `Chariot` which is what you probably want.  If all you really need are just the values you are returning, then you can write the code without `new`:

```
var board = {
  a1: CHESSMAN.Chariot('red'),
  b1: CHESSMAN.Horse('red'),
  c1: CHESSMAN.Elephant('red'),
  //etc.
```